# How should I seal my asphalt driveway?

Tags: asphalt

Websites like [familyhandyman](https://www.familyhandyman.com/project/how-to-seal-an-asphalt-driveway/) explain how to seal my asphalt driveway.

However, last year I tried filling in the cracks and the Home Store crack filler has deteriorated.

Is there a better procedure for prepping my driveway and fill the cracks and sink holes?  Or should I have it re-paved?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Comment: I have "read it on the internet" than asphalt is actually a poor choice for driveway paving because it requires the regular passing of traffic to keep it compacted and in good condition. There's just not enough traffic on a driveway for this, but there is on a public road. Therefore, concrete is a far better driveway surface. Concrete is, of course, more expensive to install... NOTE: take this with the grain of salt implied by "read it on the internet" - i.e. I have no facts to back this up.

Comment: It's probably also nation dependent on how common this is. I've mostly seen tiled driveways, concrete slabs mostly in rural areas (or where heavy vehicles are expected) and asphalt almost nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Mine looks about like that. The problem is that all those cracks are there due to movement. Moisture, frost, and traffic are constantly flexing the slab, and the older it gets the drier and more brittle it is.

It's difficult to fill or seal things that move. Most asphalt concrete experts will tell you that it's about done-for. There's nothing you can put on it that won't look the same next year.

Comment: Downvoter, care to comment?

Comment: @isherwood  Interesting that you believe movement.  1/2 my driveway is at a slight angle down to the road.  Are you suggesting that the asphalt is sliding down over time?  If so, that seems like something I should have company look into...

Comment: Not horizontal movement. Up and down, due to weather and traffic. That's what wrecks _every_ asphalt paving.